# How to handle missing inputs for spectrogram plot?

Tags: python, exception, scipy, signals, spectrogram

I am trying to plot the spectrogram of a signal using the python package : **scipy.signal.spectrogram**.

My query is what if my input signal have missing data for a time period (t1 - t2) as shown in the attached image.[image]

- Is it good to pass the data for spectrogram calculation even the input have some missing parts as shown above ?
  or
- (Obviously this missing input time period reflects in spectrogram output) Is it ok to fill the minimum value for that missing time period by handling externally after calculating spectrogram like shown below ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is neither problematic to use data with missing parts nor to interpolate the dataset. One should mention that certain portions of the data are interpolated though to avoid misinterpretation. So the non-interpolated dataset would be the "more explicit" one.

I've modified [an example of scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) to show the effect of missing data during evaluation, and what the effect of an interpolation would be:

[image]

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)

def get_spectro(x, fs, ax, title):
    f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs)
    ax.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx, shading='gouraud')
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time [sec]')
    ax.set_ylim((2500, 3500))
    ax.set_title(title)


# get oscillating frequency
fs = 10e3
N = 1e5
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)
noise_power = 0.01 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
mod = 500 * np.cos(2 * np.pi * 0.25 * time)
carrier = amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 3e3 * time + mod)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)
noise *= np.exp(-time / 5)
x = carrier + noise
get_spectro(x, fs, ax1, 'full dataset')

# replace middle part by nan
x[40000:50000] = np.nan
get_spectro(x, fs, ax2, 'missing data')

# interpolate the missing section linearly
x[np.isnan(x)] = np.interp(np.squeeze(np.argwhere(np.isnan(x))), np.squeeze(np.argwhere(~np.isnan(x))), x[~np.isnan(x)])
get_spectro(x, fs, ax3, 'interpolated data')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.8)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Is it okay to manually add a minimum value in spectrogram output for that missing time period as shown in fig 2: spectrogram to visualise it correctly ?

Comment: @BhanuchanderUdhayakumar I would argue that the "correct" visualization is the uninterpolated one. Any interpolation is based on the assumption that "nothing happens here" instead of "we might be missing something here". If you think (or ideally have some reasoning behind it) that nothing happens in the missed slots, then yes, an interpolation would be suitable. Elsewise I would stay with the the partially missing dataset.